# How to get a cryptographically strong number in the range [0,1)?

Tags: javascript, random, cryptography

I've been trying to create a function that will return a random decimal number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive) via the `Window.crypto.getRandomValues()` function. Currently, my code is as follows:

```
var rand = function(){
    var ra = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0];
    function dec(n,m){
        return (n>=0&&n<=1)?n:dec(n/m,m);
    }
    return dec(ra,8);
}
```

My problem is that this isn't uniformly distributed; it tends to be between .2 and .7, and rarely falls under .2 and over .7. Is there a better way to use the `.getRandomValues()` method to obtain a number like that of the `Math.random()` function?

I am not using the `.random()` method because I wish to have secure numbers for what I am trying to perform.

Comment: [Related question on crypto.SE.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/31657/uniformly-distributed-secure-floating-point-numbers-in-0-1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not simplify things

```
function cryptoRandom() {
    return window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint32Array(1))[0] / 0x100000000;
}
```

What's going on here?

- Assume `window.crypto.getRandomValues` will giving us truely random bits
- Ask for 32 bits (unsigned integer `i`)
- The `min`ium value of `i` is `0x00000000` (or `0`)
- The `max`imum value of `i` is `0xFFFFFFFF` (or `4294967295`)
- Transform these points onto the range you want; `(i - min) / (max + 1)`

Comment: Thanks! What does the `0x100000000` mean? I've been coding for just a bit, and was never formally taught.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien that is hexidecimal notation for `4294967296`, which is special because it is `Math.pow(2, 32)`, i.e. the number of different values a 32-bit integer can have

Comment: Thanks again for everything!

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Oh to help you understand a bit better, `0x` at the start is just us saying "this is a hex literal", then each digit after will be in `[0-9A-F]`, where `A` means `10`, `B` is `11` ... `F` is `15`. Finally, each column is now `16`s instead of `10`s, i.e. `10` in hex is `16` in dec. It's really useful for computers because 16 is a power of two (and `16 * 16 - 1` is `FF = 255`, i.e. the maximum value of a byte) which is what computers work with so you're basically writing computer-useful binary in shorthand.

Comment: This doesn't use the whole 53 bits a double mantissa offers. I'd prefer generating two `UInt32` values and combining them, or generating one 64 bit value.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I don't know enough about _Float_ to know how to choose `Uint`s to create a `Float64Array` which would have length `1` and it's first item in the range `0..1`. If you know, please post an answer! Converting _Floats_ and _Uints_ is as easy as `f = new Float64Array(uint_arr.buffer)[0]`, `uint_arr = new Uint32Array(f_arr.buffer)`, `f_arr = new Float64Array(1); f_arr[0] = f`.